# Showing Android In-App-Review dialog by the push of a button?

Tags: android, google-play

In the [guidelines for the new in-app review dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#when-to-request), Google say that

> Your app should not ask the user any questions before or while presenting the rating button or card, including questions about their opinion (such as “Do you like the app?”) or predictive questions (such as “Would you rate this app 5 stars”).

Since it says *should*, and not *must not*, it's not clear if it's an actual violation of some policy to go ahead and ask the user if they would like to leave a review before showing the dialog. The reasons for doing so are plenty, for example to minimize intrusion in the users workflow and let them leave a review when it's convenient for them.

However, in those guidelines it also says

> calling a launchReviewFlow method might not always display a dialog.

I haven't yet had time to implement the app review dialog, but I'm guessing one could simply fall back on redirecting the user to the Play Store if the dialog won't show?

What I'm wondering is - how strict are these types of guidelines from Google? Are they more like friendly advice than Play Store policy? What could happen if one does something that is recommended against ("should")?

Comment: There are many applications presenting controversial to this guideline recommendation. And Google is not taking any action against this as far as I observed. So I think this is only a recommendation from Google.

Answer (score 1):

> The reasons for doing so are plenty, for example to minimize intrusion
> in the users workflow and let them leave a review when it's convenient
> for them.

In my opinion inconvenience is same whether user dismisses your custom dialog to ask for rating or the one displayed by in-app review api.

Though custom dialog can be shown as frequently as you want. For in-app review dialog, Google has put some unknown frequency restrictions. In my opinion asking for review every couple of weeks is fair enough.

Comment: True if using a dialog, perhaps I should have clarified that I meant for example displaying a "Do you want to rate the app"-banner at the top or bottom, so the user can keep using the app and click the banner (or dismiss it) when it's convenient for them, not when I think it's convenient for them.